# How to sort contents of an <xsl:variable>

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sortedResults xmlns="urn:com-avaneesh-abc:v1">
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-11T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="16886888"/>
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-13T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="16886890"/>
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-10T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="16886884"/>
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-10T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="16886878"/>
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-13T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="16886886"/>
    <result time-zone="America/Chicago" event-end-dt-tm="2013-06-11T15:37:00.000-05:00"
                        event-id="1688687416886876"/>
</sortedResults>
```

I would like to sort the above sample XML which is part of an `<xsl:variable>` to be sorted by the `event-end-dt-tm` of each and every `<result>` and move the latest date under one XML tag `<first>`, oldest under `<last>` and the remaining ones under tag `<other>`. I tried to use `<xsl:sort>`, but it's not sorting as expected.

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have tried, please? In particular, can you clarify what you mean by saying the XML is part of an `<xsl:variable>`? Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, by the way? Thanks.

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you want to do some grouping as well as sorting. But it's not at all clear, for example do you want a single `<other>` element, or one `<other>` element for each distinct date? Showing the output you want usually helps to explain the requirements.

Comment: I just want three categories, one with the latest, the other with oldest and the remaining all goes into other(single other). The caveat is lets say there are two time stamps of today, 3 of yesterday and 2 of day before yesterday they will go into the corresponding groups as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT-1.0 will sort all `<result>` children of `<sortedResults>` by the attribute `@event-end-dt-tm` while being namespace aware to the namespace `urn:com-avaneesh-abc:v1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ava="urn:com-avaneesh-abc:v1">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/ava:sortedResults">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="@event-end-dt-tm" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ava:result">
    <!-- Put your desired processing here !!! -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@event-id" /><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  <!-- For example the @event-id followed by a newline -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```